# converting .liquid to .php? Shopify Theme to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shopify, liquid

I'm an amateur so be gentle.  I own a Shopify store and I am in the process of creating a product forum hosted outside of Shopify in Wordpress, using a subdomain. (Why? Because embedding a forum like Tal.ki, didn't quite work so well)

I want to make the transition as smooth as possible when navigating to the forum; ideally the customer wouldn't even know they have left the store.  Problem is, my sexy liquid theme from Shopify doesn't play nice with php and wordpress.

Is there anything out there that will convert liquid, particularly for people without an enormous amount of technical skills, like myself.

Thanks in advance

W

Answer (score 0):

I'm no liquid zen master myself, but if I wanted to do what you're describing, I'd take a look at the php port of liquid:  https://github.com/harrydeluxe/php-liquid

Without having looked through that carefully, my guess would still be it's not going to be particularly simple to put together the specific solution you've described.

Fwiw, it looks like you can embed disqus in shopify product pages (and therefore elsewhere, I'd presume): http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/disqus

Presuming that you largely want customers to be able to discuss particular products, working at it from that angle would probably be an easier path.  I can think of a lot of ways that could work well (beyond having disqus threads on specific product pages, you could create shopify pages with or without product collections on them to serve more as discussion hubs, and also integrate that all more easily with the native shopify blogging functionality).

Comment: Thanks Mark, that liquid template engine for php is great.  When the time comes to move away from Shopify completely, I will definitely need this.  Now the question is how to apply that templating engine to the wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing nothing here but "Skinning a forum" to look like your Shopify theme, there is no Liquid for you to even deal with. Your forum HAS NO LIQUID. It is what it is. If you want your forum to look like your Shopify store, just copy your CSS over to the theme and hack at the theme of your forum.

Therefore, this question is off-topic and instead should be asking how to take a set of CSS for one application and apply it to another.

Comment: Thanks David.  I'm not allowed to "up-vote" here as I don't have the min reputation.  So the question is how to take a CSS Stylesheet from Shopify and inserting it into WordPress.  Thanks for putting me on the correct path

Comment: All WP sites use CSS. It is standard and I am sure you can figure that out. The real challenge will be to use the CSS from your Shopify store with WP forums... there in lies the true work.